# Android Java: Cursor on SQLite slow on emulator and some devices

Tags: java, android, performance, cursor, emulation

I released an app some weeks ago and many of my users are complaining about the low speed of the app.
When I test my app I'm using a tablet and it works fine without any problem.

Now I tested the app on the emulator on Android 2.2 and saw that the app is really slow while loading some datas form my SQLite Databse.
I found out that the Cursor.moveToFirst() Method is extremely slow and forces the emulator to freeze for about 1 minute. This could be the reasson why my users are telling me that there is a forceclose when they open this Activity or the app is slow while loading it :|

I'm loading up to 700 columns with each only one value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: posting your code would help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries are performed on the UI thread by default. It sounds like you are querying an immense amount of information (700 columns worth) and that this is blocking the UI thread for a significant period of time. You should perform your query asyncronously using a `CursorLoader` or an `AsyncTask` so you don't block the UI thread (as if the UI thread is blocked for 4-5 seconds, the app will force close with an "Application not responding" error).

Comment: I can't use AsyncTask on some devices... AsyncTask is available since SDK 11 and many of my users are using SDK 10 or less. I will test it with the CursorLoader

Comment: AsyncTask is available since SDK 3, actually... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: ok, now I implemented the AsyncTask. The UI is now faster but it still takes alot of time to read the datas out of the Cursor. ... CursorLoader seems to be somethink like AsyncTask. Is this right?

Comment: `CursorLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>` which uses an `AsyncTask` to perform the query on a background thread. 700 columns is going to take a lot of time no matter how you query it... is there really any need to query *all* of this data? Do you really need it all at once? Why not query only the data you really need?

Comment: I query those 700 columns to show many informations in one list. But I only load an ID and I query more informations when my ListViewAdapter is loading one ID. Those 700 columns are filtered in this query... could a large SQL query be the reason for the low speed? If yes I will rework my filters to speed it up

Comment: Do you mean 700 rows?? Does each record actually have 700 columns?? Maybe you should post more code.